# Xamarin- how to you AuAudioUnit to generate tones?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Xamarin- how to you  AuAudioUnit to generate tones?

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.AudioUnit.AudioUnit/

Comment: I was hoping for a example. I feel like that does not tell you what the functions do